# How to fast the contacts loading in listview on android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts

in my app i am listing contacts in a listview. no of contacts is 1000+. i get the contacts

by using **ContentResolver query** that is  cr.query(...),store the values in an arraylist

and after that load the array list in setListAdapter(...). to display the all contacts my

apps takes nearly 1 minute so that i use Async task but there is no big differences by using the async task.

i need to display all contacts within 2 to 4 seconds. i check in the **default contacts 
application on android simulator which is load within in 2 to 4 seconds.**   i have spend

long time in google. but i could not get any helpful solution. please help me how to fast the loading contacts on listview. please help me.

my coding sample:

```
    private ArrayList<ContactListEntry> loadContactListInternal(String searchString) {
        ArrayList<ContactListEntry> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactListEntry>();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = null;
    String[] projection = new String[] {BaseColumns._ID,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID};
    ....
        cur=cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
         int id = Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(0));
             ....   
        if (input !=null)
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
         ....
        ArrayList<ContactListEntry.PhoneEntry> phoneEntries = new ArrayList<ContactListEntry.PhoneEntry>();

            String[] projection1 = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE};    
            Cursor pcur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,projection1, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null);
            while (pcur.moveToNext()) {
                ...
            }
            pcur.close();

            ContactListEntry entry = new ContactListEntry(id, name, photo, phoneEntries);
            contactList.add(entry);
    }
    cur.close();

    return contactList;
}
    .....
    in another class
        private void selectionUpdated() {
                ....
         setListAdapter(new SelectedArrayAdapter(this, app.selectedContacts));
            ... 
       }
```

Comment: What exactly do you **show** in the list view?

Comment: i show contacts name and phone number with check box on the right side and for next process i store other values.

Comment: Here is one more thread where we tried improving the performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546047/fetching-a-large-number-of-contacts/9546248#9546248. As you can see again I was the only one daring to answer. The OP didn't find any cleaner solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use cursor adapter and i cut the databse,arrayadapter and optimize the code.

Comment: can you explain how, I'm having the same problam. i am currently using array adapter.

Comment: @Vikas Rana, My data is in cursor (Database) so that I used cursor Adapter,in your case how much of data you have in arraylist?

Comment: I am adding phone number,name and contact photo in arraylist without storing it to database

Comment: Can you please Exaplain how ?

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that you do a lot of subqueries for each contact. I has the same issue once upon a time. My case was that I showed many contacts and allowed the user to click on any of them. After that I started processing the contact in another activity.

Back then I finally decided that I should display only the name and lazily fetch all the other data later on, just before I launch the next activity. This was amazing: decreased the speed of my program almost by a factor of 200, and the operations became completely invisible to the user.

The default android list does the same if I am not wrong - it displays only the name, and later on loads all the other contact-related data.

Comment: yes i use two queries for get detail that is in the first query i get id,name... and in the second query i pass contact id as parameter to get the phone number and type. but two query is need(that is subquery) to get phone no and such detail. is any way combine into one or in a single query to get all detail? please my queries in question.

Comment: @murali_ma you don't use two queries. You use `n + 1` queries where n is the number of contacts in the phone. I will search a bit more about that, but back then I tried doing the same as your idea and it was futile.

Answer (score 0):

Consider having just one query and getting rid of the sub query idea (as already suggested). You can achieve speed by just querying using the Content Uri:

```
"ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI"
```

This URI also has the "ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME" field.

You might also want to consider doing this query and working with your adapter in a seperate thread to make it completely transparent.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

OPTIMIZED SOLUTION HERE.....

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    };
.
.
.

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            try {
                final int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                final int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                String name, number;
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                    number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
```

CHEERS...:)