# Android: How to load and display 1000 contacts into listview faster?

Tags: android

I want to load & display over 1000 contacts from default address book of my phone into `listview`. And my solution is 2 steps:

1. get all contacts from default address book of my phone and store all of them into a cursor.
2. In my `listview` i have set `cursor adapter` with the `cursor` (using code: mylistview.setAdapter(curAdaptor))

OK, below is the code of mine:
1. As I said above. I query and get all contacts with name, phone number and company of them.

```
public Cursor getContacts() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, "DISPLAY_NAME ASC");


    String phoneNo = "";
    String company = "";

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {

            //get ID & Name of the contact
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            //get phone number
            Cursor pCur =       cr.query(   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                new String[]{id}, 
                                null);

            phoneNo = (pCur.moveToNext()) ? pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)) : "Update";

            //get company
            String orgWhere =   ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + 
                                " = ? AND " + 
                                ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
            String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{ id, 
                                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

            Cursor orgCur = cr.query(   ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                                        null, 
                                        orgWhere, 
                                        orgWhereParams, 
                                        null);
            company = (orgCur.moveToNext()) ? orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA)) : "Update";

            //put new values into extras cursor
            try {
                extras.addRow(new String[] {id,
                                            name,
                                            phoneNo,
                                            company });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR CURSOR: ", e.getMessage());
            }         
            orgCur.close();
            pCur.close();
        } 
    } 
    return extras;
}
```

1. The second step:

   ```
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   extras = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id", "contactName", "Phone", "Company" });

   ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ops = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ();
   ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
           .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
           .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
           .build());      

   Cursor cur = getContacts(); 

   String[] from = new String[]{
           "_id",
           "contactName", 
           "phone", 
           "company"
   };
   int[] to = new int[] {
           R.id.contactId, 
           R.id.contactName, 
           R.id.phone, 
           R.id.company
   };

   try {
       curAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
               getApplicationContext(), 
               R.layout.view_contact_entry, 
               cur, 
               from, 
               to, 0);
       lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
       lv.setAdapter(curAdapter);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("ERROR: ", e.getMessage());
   }       

   //show all data onto listview
   lv = getListView();
   ```

   }

Ok, that is my problem: With the solution, I spent about 13s to load and display all contact into listview. I want to load and display faster! What should I do. OR could you show me another way to solve the problem such as: using lazy listview in android, etc...

Comment: BETTER SOLUTION HERE....

http://stackoverflow.com/a/28690064/1881527

CHEERS....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load some items that cover all the list height and then load other items if user scroll the list to browse theme(when item comes to be visible).You can see Async loading section of [Performance Tips for Android’s ListView](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) or search in web in about `Lazy Loading ListView`.

Comment: Thanks hasanghaforian, let me try this one!