# ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER does not work as expected

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have been searching for a very fast way to load contacts in my android application. I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28690064/5670752) and it worked! My contacts load super fast now.

There is only one problem however, the solution involves using the array below to query the contacts:

```
private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
};
```

Obviously, `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` retrieves the phone number.

The problem I'm currently facing is that this field only retrieves phone numbers with country codes. Therefore, it can easily detect *+2347000000000* but not *07000000000*. I want to be able to detect phone numbers without country codes.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google's libphonenumber library in order to add/remove country codes to phones, see here:
https://github.com/google/libphonenumber (read the readme regarding usage in Android)

here's a relevant snippet for your use-case:

````
There are a few formats supported by the formatting method, as illustrated below:

// Produces "+41 44 668 18 00"
System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL));
// Produces "044 668 18 00"
System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL));
// Produces "+41446681800"
System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.E164));
You could also choose to format the number in the way it is dialed from another country:

// Produces "011 41 44 668 1800", the number when it is dialed in the United States.
System.out.println(phoneUtil.formatOutOfCountryCallingNumber(swissNumberProto, "US"));```
````

Comment: Thank you. How do I implement this in my current use case? Is it in the `Cursor.getColumnIndex` method? It seems to be null and that's probably why it's being skipped. Kindly shed some morel light on this.

Comment: no, this is not related to the cursor, you'll need to first get all the phone numbers from the contacts DB as your code does, and then iterate over then, and create two versions for each phone, one with country code and one without, you can use the library in my answer to accomplish that

Comment: Thank you very much but my major concern is speed. I have used other approaches but this is the fastest one yet. The problem with this one is that it only returns phone numbers with country codes. It uses the cursor to generate these numbers. I'm searching for a way to optimize my current approach so that it returns ALL phone numbers regardless of their format. Your current suggestion does not afford me that opportunity because the cursor generates the numbers.

Comment: the second loop where you go over the phones you got from the cursor and convert them to with/without country code should be negligible compared to the time it takes to get the initial query in your code. just try it.